# add value to String array in JSP

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to add another value to a an Array..

```
<%= ProductManager.getAddItems(new String[] {((String)pageContext.getAttribute("skuId"))}, (Order)pageContext.getAttribute("order"), request,response) %>
```

I want to add pageContext.getAttribute("qty") to the above String array but just can't seem to get it to work.  Google the subject to death and not finding any examples of what I'm trying to accomplish..   any suggestions would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You are creating array of string and you are putting string and Order both different object in the array how it will work..?

Comment: No, the array only has one element, the one with the string cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (havent tried it in in a console yet though)

```
<%= ProductManager.getAddItems(new String[] {((String)pageContext.getAttribute("skuId")), ((String)pageContext.getAttribute("qty"))}, (Order)pageContext.getAttribute("order"), request,response) %>
```

Comment: Awesome.. but I could have sworn I tried that..  it does work though :)

Comment: I think you can remove the outer-parentheses for both strings in the array aswell, just for the sake of better readability :)